# How to return observer or promise in canActivate Angular?

Tags: angular

I use the following code to check if user can activate route and if there is a token:

```
export const canActivateAuthRoute: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Promise<boolean> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    debugger;
    const configService = inject(ConfigService);
    const authService = inject(AuthService);
    const userService = inject(UserService);

    const code = parseUrlParam(configService.config.auth.paramCode);
    const token = authService.getToken();
    const appMode = route.data['mode'];

    if (token) return resolve(true);
    if (appMode) localStorage.setItem('url', window.location.href);
    if (code) {
      authService
        .loadToken(configService.config.authUrlToken, code)
        .subscribe((token: string) => {
          authService.setToken(token);
          userService.setUser(token);
          window.location.href = localStorage.getItem('url');
        });
    } else if (!token) {
      window.location.href = configService.config.authTustTokenUrl;
    } else {
      return resolve(true);
    }
  });
};
```

Problem is when I do resolve(true); inside subscriptoin result the primise is failed.

Comment: I think you just need to handle the error as well. I guess you are getting  some error response, that you are not handling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this, But your code also should work(**you just need to handle the error response as well**, I guess you are getting the error response from the API), I can't see any issues in it(**But I recommend you to use RxJS**).

```
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const canActivateAuthRoute: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): boolean | Observable<boolean> => {
    const configService = inject(ConfigService);
    const authService = inject(AuthService);
    const userService = inject(UserService);
    const code = parseUrlParam(configService.config.auth.paramCode);
    
    if (authService.getToken()) { return true; }

    if (code) {
     return authService
        .loadToken(configService.config.authUrlToken, code)
        .pipe(
           // tap you need to store the token information in your services
           tap((token: string) => {
                 authService.setToken(token);
                 userService.setUser(token);
           }),
           // this will convert the value to boolean
           // this is the conversion to Observable<boolean>
           map(token => !!token),
           catchError(error => {
              // do redirection or something
              // and do of(false) to block the navigation
              of(false);
           })
        );
    }

    // I recommend you to review this piece of code and change 
    if (!authService.getToken()) {
      window.location.href = configService.config.authTustTokenUrl;
      return false; // ?
    }
};
```

Comment: Not all code paths return a value.ts(703

Comment: It does not work for me when I do resolve(true)

Comment: Hello @MeganClerc, you will need to add .catch handlers as well, to make it work for all of the cases.